# How can I defined the type of a dictionary whose keys are **some** of the values of union literal type?

Tags: typescript

In type script I have a union literal type defined as

```js
export type Color =
  | 'red'
  | 'green'
  | 'blue'
  | 'teal'
  | 'purple'
```

How can I defined the type of a dictionary whose keys are **some** of the values of `Color` and the keys as string?

For instance:

```js
const COLOR_MAP = {
  red: 'Cool',
  aree: 'Not so cool'
}
```

How can I typize `COLOR_MAP` so that I can access its set values with a string whose type is `Color`?

Comment: I think I dont get it. Do wo want to type COLOR_MAP? const COLOR_MAP: Color would do the trick. Then you can access it by COLOR_MAP.red or COLOR_MAP["red"]

Comment: const COLOR_MAP: Color doesn't do the trick because Color is a string and COLOR_MAP is a dictionary whose keys are a subset of Color

Comment: Well then it might be const COLOR_MAP: Record<Color, string> = ...

Comment: Again, nope: Record<Color, string> would want ALL the string literals defined in Color. If you try it out the code I posted, it'll say that it's missing 'blue', 'teal' etc. That's why I keep referring to the keys as as SUBSET of the literal type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Record<Color, string>` or `{ [key in Color]: string }` for an exhaustive map.

Use `Partial<Record<Color, string>>` or `{ [key in Color]?: string }` for a non-exhaustive map.

If you want some specific subset of the union that is known at compile-time you can use `Extract`:

```
Record<Extract<Color, 'red' | 'teal'>, string>
```